# Size of font in ggplot plot changes in relation to plot using knitr

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, knitr

I'm using knitr for the first time, and have a problem concering the font size in ggplot plots. This is an example plot:

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = clarity))
d + stat_sum(aes(label=..n..),geom="text",size=8)
```

In knitr I have the same plot in a chunk in my R markdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = clarity))
d + stat_sum(aes(label=..n..),geom="text",size=8)
```
````

The plot looks fine in RStudio or when saved with ggsave(). However the numbers in the plot in the resulting knitr html have a much larger font size, in total and relative to the plot size:

[image: ggsave image] [image: knitr image from html]

In this example it does not matter much, but in my data the numbers start to overlap each other / run out of their cells.

An added complication is that the plot is done by a package, so I can't easily change the size option in the stat_sum call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adjusting `fig.height` and `fig.width`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE,fig.height=10,fig.width=10}
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = clarity))
d + stat_sum(aes(label=..n..),geom="text",size=8)
```
````

If you want don't want the figure to be as large, you can adjust `out.height` and `out.width`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE,fig.height=10,fig.width=10,out.height=600,out.width=600}
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = clarity))
d + stat_sum(aes(label=..n..),geom="text",size=8)
```
````

Comment: That works, thanks. Still don't understand why that changes the font relative to the plot size, but I'm happy for now.

Comment: Just noticed while the plot looks nice now, the caption I add with fig.cap="foobar" disappears. Is it "behind" the plot?

Comment: You have it set up to output as an html document.  The caption in this mode displays when you mouseover.  Are you converting html to something else after you run it?

Comment: I just saw this is the expected behaviour: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/174

Comment: Regarding the change in font size, the dimension of the default "device" used by `knitr` is different than the size of the device used by your R console, so the font size is actually the same in both cases, it's the size of the actual plot that changes.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks!